# Can't export deployable features in Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I am trying to export a couple of deployable features in Luna, but I always get the error message below. I have two plug-in projects, a corresponding feature project for each and a category definition. With this set up Kepler exported the deployable features into a folder flawlessly, but with Luna there is always this message.

How can this be solved? Is there any other relevant information I can post?

**Message:**

```
An internal error occurred during: "Export Features".
```

**Exception Stack Trace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.NativeCodeSpecificationImpl.isSatisfiedBy(NativeCodeSpecificationImpl.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.module.ResolverImpl.isResolvable(ResolverImpl.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.module.ResolverImpl.resolveBundles(ResolverImpl.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.module.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateImpl.resolve(StateImpl.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateImpl.resolve(StateImpl.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.site.BuildTimeSite.getRegistry(BuildTimeSite.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.BuildScriptGenerator.generateFeatures(BuildScriptGenerator.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.BuildScriptGenerator.generate(BuildScriptGenerator.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.doExport(FeatureExportOperation.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.doExport(FeatureExportOperation.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.run(FeatureExportOperation.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

**Session Data:**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -data /media/lads/Data/users/lads/Trabalho/Eclipse/Luna/Workspace.Acceleo -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with release 4.4.0 reported in [Bug 438652](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438652). A fix was shipped with release 4.4.1, thus an update to Eclipse gets this functionality working again.